# Chrome tabs not responding and not showing in task manager

Tags: google-chrome

From time to time (usually at least once a day) when I click the + to open a new tab in Chrome, a new tab opens but nothing is displayed. Typing in the omni bar does nothing, and the tab is not even listed in Chrome's task manager.  To correct the problem I have to restart the browser (making sure to kill all instances in Windows task manager).

I'm using Windows XP and the latest version of Chrome (as of today 9.0.597.94).  Is this a known issue, and are there any fixes available for this issue?

I've searched the web, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the assumption that your current tab still works and thus the internet is working fine:

1. Have you tried the previous stable version, or perhaps a beta or dev version to resolve this?
2. This most likely might be an extension problem, try to disable them to see if it resolves the problem.
3. If not, [back-up and create a new user profile](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059) to see if your user profile might be corrupt.

Comment: I have seen this behavior on many versions, on different PCs, and with/without extensions running. And yes the current tab still works.

Comment: Different PCs in the same network, or doesn't that matter? What was the home page set to, about:blank? Perhaps your omni bar isn't functioning and I would think that a new tab with nothing in doesn't take memory thus doesn't show up?

Comment: Network does not matter.  Home page is set to Google.com. When working correctly the new tab does show in the task manager and the omni bar works fine, the new tab only fails to show up when the problem is encountered.

Comment: No idea, you might want to [consider reporting the bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) with sufficient details or opening up a bounty here.